# How can I remove the left space between back button and SearchView

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I keep having a big white space in the left of my `Toolbar` between the back button and `SearchView`. My xml file looks like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In my `Activity` I add a back button like below

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

if I set it to false it works okay. But I need to have a back button. Is there a way to solve it? Thank you.

I didn't use a `menu layout`.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a snapshot, @mori ?

Comment: @Alessio I added a snapshot. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SearchView in OptionsMenu not full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063103/searchview-in-optionsmenu-not-full-width)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, `Toolbar` have 16dp inset after backbutton. So, include `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` in `Toolbar`, it will remove that whitespace.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
```

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines in your     Toolbar

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this property in the `SearchView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="-16dp"
            android:paddingStart="-16dp"/>
```

and check it. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use MaxWidth option to do it programmatically in onCreateOptionsMenu() method

```
@override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

if using Kotlin use:

```
searchView.maxWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE
```