# The space between the back button and the search view is too much - is it possible to reduce it on the toolbar?

Tags: android

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/style_toolbar_textView" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <View style="@style/style_toolbar_shadow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**menu_events_ppl_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menuSearchId"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          android:icon="@drawable/search_material"
          android:title="@string/str_search"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**code**

```
/** Init On create options menu **/
    private fun initOnCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_events_ppl_list, menu)

        val search = toolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearchId).actionView as SearchView
        search.queryHint = "Search People";
        //search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        search.isIconified = false
        search.maxWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

---

**What I am trying to display**

[image]

**What is displaying**

[image]

**Space between back button and search view is more in android, is it possible to reduce it ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Toolbar have 16dp inset after backbutton. So, include `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` in Toolbar, it will remove that whitespace.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
   ..........
   ..........
   app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
   ..........
   ..........
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

The original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47217539/4291272)

Answer (score -1):

Change `showAsAction` of the menu xml. This is exactly what you are looking for.

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
```